# Is using/linking an automated trading program to a brokerage platform legal?

Tags: online-trading, online-brokerage

I have no experience in programming, but I see some brokerage firms have its own scripting/coding tool inside its desktop platform, and I also see an API programs,, my question is are there a companion agreement between those programs and the brokerage firm? if yes, what is the point of let clients use those programs instead of their own scripting tool ? (I'm a beginner)

Comment: Does the broker not provide this information in their terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many systems that allow 3rd party access to their data through an API have a way of limiting the number of calls or the amount of data accessed. They sell greater access.

This is traditionally done with an API key. To do a handful of calls requires no key, to allow X calls per hour requires you to register for API access. To make even more calls requires a API key that costs money. They may even sell unlimited access.

All this is separate from the username/password system that is need to get to specific data.

If you try to exceed their limits they can block your API calls, until the next time period. Frequently trying to exceed the limits can lead to a total blockage.

Comment: are the systems that allowed third party access are called open-source or their is a different term? (i'm a beginner)

Comment: Open source is something else https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source. Take twitter. It has an API, so you can search and post. But it isn't open source. They don't let you modify the code.